# how to set environment oracle about numbering on php

Tags: php, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

In SQL Developer I have an query like this

```
select 0.4 num from dual;
```

that's code returning 0.4, but if i run in php that's query return .4
how to solve this problem ? because i have many table in my database

thanks.

Comment: That is just a display issue.  If you want a particular format, use `to_char()` to convert the value to a string.

Comment: i have many table in my database and it's have a complex query, 
if I miss a configuration should I run a php script ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're using OCI to connect Oracle with PHP. Therefore, it is not possible because OCI omit zeros in results and PHP convert results to strings. You must implement a wrapper on your queries and use number_format or sprintf function to convert to correct format.

Regards